# Not able to parse JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: json, parsing, file

I am using JavaScript to Parse the JSON file. But I am not able understand the error I am getting. Could anybody please help me on this topic.

**My Code:
Html file:

```
<title>JSON Parser</title> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function webGLStart() {  
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open("GET","test.json");
       var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
     alert (my_JSON_object.result[0]);
    }

</script>  
</head>  
<body onload="webGLStart();">  
</body>  
</html>
```

test.json File:

```
{"result": [0,1,2,3,4] }
```

alert in above code does not show anything on the webpage.

Answer (score 6):

It's straight forward with jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {         
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        console.log("key=" + key + " " + "val=" + val);
    });
});
```

For more sample code look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3):

Your code for making the Ajax request is not correct.

First, `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();` will not work incase of IE 5, 6; i.e. you need to make cross-browser object of XMLHttp

Second, `request.open("GET","test.json");` does not indicate this request to be asynchronous... i.e. you are missing the third boolean parameter (true / false)

Thirdly, you are not sending the request to the web server using:

```
request.send(null);
```

Try following link for Ajax:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Try this link for Parsing JSON using Javascript:

http://json.org/js.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous. You are trying to read the response before it has arrived from the server. Oh, worse than that. You are opening the request but never actually sending it.

You need to use an event handler onreadystate change to run the code once the response has arrived, and you need to send the request to the server before you can get a response. There is a [decent guide to using XHR here](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).